# Received geo data of Riyadh traffic from HERE api as shape points, how to load them into geopandas?

Tags: geospatial, here-api, geopandas, geo, fiona

I'm new to geospatial data, and I've collected some traffic flow data of Riyadh using HERE API by using this request url:

```
requests.get(f"https://data.traffic.hereapi.com/v7/flow?locationReferencing=shape&in=bbox:46.278534,24.377121,47.040710,25.084355&advancedFeatures=deepCoverage&apiKey={HERE['apikey']}")
```

they have 3 ways of describing a location, check here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic-api/dev_guide/topics/concepts/location-referencing.html, and the only one that shows coordinates in the response is Shape Points.
I need the response with coordinates in order to manipulate and visualize the data using geopandas and add more data to every linestring. however, the response goes something like this:

```
>     {"sourceUpdated": "2022-10-06T14:28:08Z", "results": [{"location": {"description": "\u0634\u0627\u0631\u0639
> \u0627\u0644\u0634\u064a\u062e \u062e\u0644\u064a\u0641\u0629
> \u0628\u0646 \u0623\u062d\u0645\u062f \u0622\u0644
> \u062b\u0627\u0646", "length": 288.0, "shape": {"links": [{"points":
> [{"lat": 24.82835004106164, "lng": 46.88801002688706}, {"lat":
> 24.828669978305697, "lng": 46.887639965862036}], "length": 52.0}, {"points": [{"lat": 24.828669978305697, "lng": 46.887639965862036},
> {"lat": 24.828799981623888, "lng": 46.88746998086572}], "length":
> 22.0}, {"points": [{"lat": 24.828799981623888, "lng": 46.88746998086572}, {"lat": 24.829199966043234, "lng": 46.886930018663406}], "length": 70.0}, {"points": [{"lat": 24.829199966043234, "lng": 46.886930018663406}, {"lat": 24.82987998984754, "lng": 46.88601999543607}], "length": 119.0}, {"points": [{"lat": 24.82987998984754, "lng": 46.88601999543607},
> {"lat": 24.830019967630506, "lng": 46.885829977691174}], "length":
> 25.0}]}}, "currentFlow": {"speed": 8.333334, "speedUncapped": 8.333334, "freeFlow": 9.722222, "jamFactor": 0.6, "confidence": 0.71, "traversability": "open"}}, {"location": {"description":
> "\u0634\u0627\u0631\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u0635\u062d\u0627\u0628\u0629",
> "length": 1103.0, "shape": {"links": [{"points": [{"lat":
> 24.803550001233816, "lng": 46.769810020923615}, {"lat": 24.803940011188388, "lng": 46.770779974758625}], "length": 107.0}, {"points": [{"lat": 24.803940011188388, "lng": 46.770779974758625},
> {"lat": 24.804060040041804, "lng": 46.77109002135694}, {"lat":
> 24.804279981181026, "lng": 46.77162000909448}], "length": 93.0}, {"points": [{"lat": 24.804279981181026, "lng": 46.77162000909448},
> {"lat": 24.804349970072508, "lng": 46.77179996855557}], "length":
> 20.0}, {"points": [{"lat": 24.804349970072508, "lng": 46.77179996855557}, {"lat": 24.80441995896399, "lng": 46.771959979087114}], "length": 18.0}, {"points": [{"lat": 24.80441995896399, "lng": 46.771959979087114}, {"lat": 24.80476001277566, "lng": 46.77283002063632}], "length": 96.0}, {"points": [{"lat": 24.80476001277566, "lng": 46.77283002063632},
> {"lat": 24.80492999777198, "lng": 46.77323997952044}], "length":
> 45.0}, {"points": [{"lat": 24.80492999777198, "lng": 46.77323997952044}, {"lat": 24.805459985509515, "lng": 46.77444001659751}], "length": 135.0}, {"points": [{"lat": 24.805459985509515, "lng": 46.77444001659751}, {"lat": 24.805540032684803, "lng": 46.77461000159383}], "length": 19.0}, {"points": [{"lat": 24.805540032684803, "lng": 46.77461000159383},
> {"lat": 24.805650003254414, "lng": 46.77487998269498}], "length":
> 30.0}, {"points": [{"lat": 24.805650003254414, "lng": 46.77487998269498}, {"lat": 24.805780006572604, "lng": 46.77513001486659}], "length": 29.0}, {"points": [{"lat": 24.805780006572604, "lng": 46.77513001486659}, {"lat": 24.805840020999312, "lng": 46.77526001818478}], "length": 15.0}, {"points": [{"lat": 24.805840020999312, "lng": 46.77526001818478},
> {"lat": 24.806040013208985, "lng": 46.77575002424419}], "length":
> 54.0}, {"points": [{"lat": 24.806040013208985, "lng": 46.77575002424419}, {"lat": 24.806360034272075, "lng": 46.7765299603343}], "length": 86.0}, {"points": [{"lat": 24.806360034272075, "lng": 46.7765299603343}, {"lat": 24.80663001537323, "lng": 46.777179976925254}], "length": 72.0}, {"points": [{"lat": 24.80663001537323, "lng": 46.777179976925254},
> {"lat": 24.807410035282373, "lng": 46.77894998341799}], "length":
> 198.0}, {"points": [{"lat": 24.807410035282373, "lng": 46.77894998341799}, {"lat": 24.807629976421595, "lng": 46.77946999669075}], "length": 58.0}, {"points": [{"lat": 24.807629976421595, "lng": 46.77946999669075}, {"lat": 24.80772997252643, "lng": 46.77972002886236}], "length": 28.0}]}}, "currentFlow": {"speed": 8.611112, "speedUncapped": 8.611112,
> "freeFlow": 10.555556, "jamFactor": 1.7, "confidence": 0.94,
> "traversability": "open", "subSegments": [{"length": 819.0, "speed":
> 10.277778, "speedUncapped": 10.277778, "freeFlow": 10.0, "jamFactor": 0.0, "confidence": 0.94, "traversability": "open"}, {"length": 284.0, "speed": 6.111111, "speedUncapped": 6.111111, "freeFlow": 11.388889,
> "jamFactor": 3.1, "confidence": 0.94, "traversability": "open"}]}},
> {"location": {"description": "\u0634\u0627\u0631\u0639
> \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0631\u0642", "length": 180.0, "shape": {"links":
> [{"points": [{"lat": 24.808140015229583, "lng": 46.886649979278445},
> {"lat": 24.808549974113703, "lng": 46.88592997379601}], "length":
> 86.0}, {"points": [{"lat": 24.808549974113703, "lng": 46.88592997379601}, {"lat": 24.80871995911002, "lng": 46.885659992694855}], "length": 33.0}, {"points": [{"lat": 24.80871995911002, "lng": 46.885659992694855}, {"lat": 24.808839987963438, "lng": 46.885469974949956}], "length": 23.0}, {"points": [{"lat": 24.808839987963438, "lng": 46.885469974949956},
> {"lat": 24.808960016816854, "lng": 46.88526998274028}], "length":
> 24.0}, {"points": [{"lat": 24.808960016816854, "lng": 46.88526998274028}, {"lat": 24.809030005708337, "lng": 46.88516001217067}], "length": 14.0}]}}, "currentFlow": {"speed": 5.277778, "speedUncapped": 5.277778, "freeFlow": 8.055555, "jamFactor": 2.5, "confidence": 0.9, "traversability": "open"}},
> {"location": {"description": "\u0634\u0627\u0631\u0639
> \u0627\u0644\u0646\u062f\u0648\u0629", "length": 19.0, "shape":
> {"links": [{"points": [{"lat": 24.80036001652479, "lng":
> 46.892340034246445}, {"lat": 24.800450038164854, "lng": 46.8921800237149}], "length": 19.0}]}}, "currentFlow": {"speed": 7.777778, "speedUncapped": 7.777778, "freeFlow": 7.777778, "jamFactor": 0.0, "confidence": 0.84, "traversability": "open"}}, ...
> ] }
```

correct me if I'm wrong, it is a messy data that needs post processing manually in order to have it supported by geopandas -fiona drivers- which are:

> {'ARCGEN': 'r',  'DXF': 'rw',  'CSV': 'raw',  'OpenFileGDB': 'r',
> 'ESRIJSON': 'r',  'ESRI Shapefile': 'raw',  'FlatGeobuf': 'rw',
> 'GeoJSON': 'raw',  'GeoJSONSeq': 'rw',  'GPKG': 'raw',  'GML': 'rw',
> 'OGR_GMT': 'rw',  'GPX': 'rw',  'GPSTrackMaker': 'rw',  'Idrisi': 'r',
> 'MapInfo File': 'raw',  'DGN': 'raw',  'PCIDSK': 'raw',  'OGR_PDS':
> 'r',  'S57': 'r',  'SQLite': 'raw',  'TopoJSON': 'r'}

I really would be happy if you show me a way that I can get the data in any supported format, or preferably in geojson.

and another question, is their location referencing static? I mean, for every time I request the traffic data, do I get the same segments of roads but with different traffic data or does the segmentation change depending on traffic?

Thank you!

Comment: Dear Customer, We have tried with the provided request and the response is in JSON format. Could you please check and confirm?

Comment: yes, it is in json format

Answer (score 1):

The HERE apis are returning the data in the JSON format. The data should be processed at application level based on the use-case.

And the answer to second query related to segments and traffic. The Segments will not change, only the traffic data will be updated.

Comment: Thank you for your response, do you have any idea of how should I preprocess the coordinates to be in LineStrings or MultiLineStrings while keeping the segments consistent and static for every file I get from the request? I tried multiple ways but all of them when I compare the linestrings produced doesn't seem like the data is consistent. I am taking every point (lat,lng) location.shapes.link and append them to my linestring, is this the way you suggest?